# Create trendline for a plot of a set of disordered data?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a totally random set of data with around 500 inputs obtained from a physics experiment in excel format. I plotted it successfully but I am not able to create a trendline for my plot. I need to find the trendline for this data.
excel data can be found from [this google drive link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eV0GSkBDdzD7i8qMiphzNBJCiNCsBf-q).
Alternatively, these are the first 2 columns of the Excel file:

```
0_x 0_y
0.321816    -82.594828
1.595041    -85.396122
2.868266    -82.085502
3.632201    -84.632133
4.905426    -83.868143
6.178651    -84.122807
7.197231    -85.905448
7.961166    -84.37747
8.470457    -85.141459
9.743682    -82.340165
10.252972   -84.886796
11.271552   -82.594828
13.054067   -84.886796
13.054067   -83.104154
14.327292   -84.632133
15.345872   -86.160112
16.364452   -84.886796
17.383032   -86.160112
18.401612   -83.868143
19.165547   -85.905448
20.438773   -82.849491
21.457353   -85.396122
22.221288   -83.104154
22.475933   -85.650785
23.494513   -85.650785
24.513093   -84.632133
25.277028   -85.141459
26.550253   -84.122807
27.314188   -85.141459
28.587413   -82.849491
29.860638   -84.886796
31.133864   -82.340165
31.897799   -84.886796
32.916379   -83.868143
33.934959   -84.37747
34.698894   -84.886796
35.717474   -84.122807
37.245344   -85.141459
38.263924   -83.104154
39.282504   -84.122807
40.301084   -81.576175
40.810374   -84.122807
42.0836 -82.085502
43.356825   -84.886796
44.12076    -85.396122
45.13934    -85.141459
45.903275   -86.669438
47.1765 -84.632133
47.940435   -85.396122
48.70437    -83.358817
49.977595   -85.396122
50.486885   -82.085502
51.25082    -84.632133
52.2694 -83.868143
52.524045   -83.868143
53.287981   -85.905448
55.070496   -84.37747
56.343721   -86.160112
57.107656   -84.122807
57.871591   -86.160112
58.635526   -83.61348
59.144816   -85.905448
60.163396   -84.122807
61.181976   -85.396122
62.709846   -86.160112
62.964491   -85.396122
64.492362   -86.669438
65.001652   -85.141459
65.765587   -85.905448
66.784167   -84.122807
68.566682   -86.160112
69.585262   -83.358817
70.349197   -85.650785
71.113132   -84.37747
72.386357   -84.632133
73.150292   -85.141459
73.914227   -83.868143
74.932807   -85.141459
75.951388   -82.594828
77.224613   -85.396122
78.752483   -82.340165
79.516418   -85.141459
80.280353   -84.122807
81.553578   -85.905448
82.317513   -85.650785
82.826803   -84.886796
83.845383   -85.905448
83.336093   -83.868143
81.808223   -85.905448
80.534998   -83.104154
79.516418   -85.905448
78.497838   -83.868143
76.969968   -85.396122
75.696743   -86.160112
74.678162   -85.396122
73.659582   -86.669438
72.641002   -85.141459
71.367777   -86.160112
69.585262   -83.61348
68.566682   -86.160112
67.548102   -84.122807
66.274877   -86.160112
65.765587   -85.650785
65.001652   -85.905448
63.728426   -86.414775
61.945911   -84.632133
60.927331   -86.160112
60.418041   -83.61348
59.144816   -85.905448
58.380881   -82.594828
57.362301   -84.886796
56.089076   -82.849491
55.325141   -85.141459
54.561206   -85.141459
53.797271   -83.61348
52.524045   -85.141459
51.505465   -83.358817
50.486885   -85.141459
49.21366    -83.104154
48.19508    -84.886796
47.431145   -82.340165
46.15792    -84.886796
45.13934    -84.37747
44.12076    -85.396122
42.847535   -85.141459
41.319664   -84.886796
40.301084   -85.396122
39.537149   -84.632133
38.009279   -85.905448
37.245344   -82.849491
35.972119   -85.396122
34.953539   -83.868143
34.189604   -85.141459
32.152444   -84.632133
31.388509   -84.632133
30.115283   -86.160112
29.351348   -83.61348
28.078123   -85.396122
27.568833   -82.594828
26.804898   -85.396122
25.786318   -82.085502
24.513093   -85.141459
23.494513   -85.141459
22.730578   -84.37747
21.711998   -84.632133
20.438773   -84.122807
19.674838   -84.632133
18.401612   -82.594828
17.383032   -84.886796
16.619097   -82.594828
15.855162   -84.122807
15.091227   -83.61348
13.818002   -84.122807
12.799422   -84.122807
11.780842   -84.122807
11.016907   -84.886796
9.743682    -82.849491
8.215811    -84.632133
7.706521    -81.830838
6.942586    -84.632133
5.414716    -83.868143
4.141491    -85.396122
3.122911    -85.396122
2.358976    -84.886796
1.085751    -85.905448
0.321816    -84.37747
-0.696764   -85.905448
-1.969989   -83.358817
-2.98857    -85.650785
-4.51644    -82.594828
-5.53502    -85.905448
-6.808245   -85.396122
-7.57218    -86.160112
-8.59076    -86.414775
-10.11863   -85.141459
-10.62792   -86.669438
-11.901145  -84.122807
-12.919725  -86.669438
-13.17437   -83.61348
-13.938306  -85.650785
-15.211531  -84.122807
-15.975466  -85.396122
-17.248691  -86.414775
-18.267271  -85.141459
-19.285851  -86.160112
-20.049786  -85.141459
-21.323011  -84.886796
-22.341591  -82.594828
-23.105526  -85.141459
-24.124106  -82.085502
-25.397332  -84.632133
-26.161267  -84.632133
-27.179847  -84.632133
-27.434492  -85.905448
-28.707717  -84.632133
-29.471652  -85.905448
-30.999522  -83.358817
-32.527392  -85.396122
-33.291327  -82.340165
-34.309907  -85.396122
-35.073842  -83.61348
-35.583132  -85.141459
-37.620293  -85.396122
-38.638873  -84.122807
-39.402808  -85.650785
-40.421388  -84.122807
-41.694613  -86.160112
-43.222483  -82.849491
-44.241063  -86.160112
-45.259643  -83.868143
-46.023578  -85.650785
-47.551449  -85.905448
-48.315384  -85.141459
-49.588609  -85.141459
-50.607189  -84.122807
-51.625769  -85.141459
-52.644349  -82.340165
-53.662929  -84.886796
-54.426864  -82.594828
-54.936154  -84.37747
-56.209379  -83.104154
-56.718669  -83.868143
-57.737249  -84.37747
-59.26512   -83.104154
-60.029055  -84.37747
-61.30228   -81.830838
-62.066215  -83.868143
-62.32086   -82.085502
-63.594085  -84.122807
-64.612665  -82.849491
-66.140535  -84.122807
-66.649825  -84.122807
-68.177695  -83.868143
-69.45092   -85.396122
-70.214856  -83.61348
-71.233436  -85.141459
-72.252016  -82.594828
-73.015951  -84.886796
-74.289176  -82.594828
-76.071691  -84.632133
-76.326336  -85.650785
-77.854206  -84.122807
-78.618141  -86.160112
-79.891366  -85.905448
-80.655301  -86.414775
-81.928527  -83.868143
-82.692462  -86.414775
-83.965687  -83.358817
-84.984267  -85.141459
-86.002847  -83.868143
-86.766782  -84.122807
-87.785362  -84.886796
-88.803942  -83.868143
-89.313232  -85.141459
-90.331812  -83.358817
-91.350392  -85.650785
-92.368973  -82.594828
-93.132908  -84.37747
-94.406133  -83.104154
-95.424713  -84.632133
-96.188648  -85.141459
-96.697938  -84.37747
-97.461873  -85.141459
-98.480453  -84.37747
-99.499033  -85.650785
-100.517613 -83.104154
-101.790838 -85.650785
-102.554773 -83.358817
-103.573354 -85.650785
-104.591934 -85.396122
-105.865159 -85.396122
-107.647674 -85.650785
-108.156964 -84.632133
-108.920899 -85.905448
-110.703414 -83.358817
-111.721994 -86.414775
-112.485929 -83.868143
-113.759154 -85.905448
-114.52309  -85.141459
-115.54167  -86.414775
-116.305605 -86.414775
-117.57883  -85.396122
-118.08812  -86.414775
-118.852055 -84.886796
-120.12528  -86.160112
-120.889215 -83.358817
-121.907795 -85.905448
-122.926375 -83.868143
-123.69031  -85.396122
-124.963535 -85.396122
-125.727471 -84.632133
-126.746051 -85.905448
-127.764631 -83.868143
-128.783211 -84.632133
-129.037856 -82.594828
-130.056436 -85.141459
-131.075016 -82.085502
-132.093596 -84.37747
-133.112176 -84.37747
-133.876111 -84.37747
-135.149336 -84.632133
-136.677207 -83.104154
-137.441142 -85.650785
-138.459722 -83.61348
-139.223657 -84.886796
-140.496882 -82.340165
-141.515462 -84.632133
-142.534042 -83.358817
-143.297977 -84.37747
-144.825847 -85.141459
-145.844427 -84.886796
-146.863007 -86.160112
-147.881588 -84.37747
-148.900168 -85.396122
-149.918748 -83.358817
-150.682683 -85.650785
-151.701263 -83.358817
-152.719843 -85.141459
-153.738423 -85.396122
-153.993068 -84.122807
-155.011648 -84.886796
-156.030228 -84.37747
-157.303453 -84.632133
-158.067388 -82.340165
-159.340614 -85.396122
-159.849904 -82.085502
-159.595259 -84.122807
-158.576678 -82.849491
-157.303453 -84.122807
-156.030228 -84.37747
-155.011648 -83.358817
-153.229133 -84.37747
-152.210553 -82.849491
-151.446618 -84.632133
-149.664103 -81.321512
-148.645523 -84.886796
-147.881588 -82.594828
-146.608362 -84.37747
-145.589782 -84.886796
-144.571202 -84.122807
-143.552622 -85.396122
-143.043332 -84.122807
-142.024752 -85.396122
-140.751527 -83.358817
-139.478302 -85.905448
-138.459722 -83.358817
-137.441142 -85.905448
-136.677207 -85.141459
-135.403981 -85.141459
-134.640046 -85.905448
-134.130756 -84.632133
-132.857531 -84.632133
-131.838951 -83.868143
-130.820371 -85.905448
-129.547146 -82.594828
-128.783211 -85.650785
-127.764631 -83.868143
-125.982116 -85.141459
-124.963535 -85.650785
-123.944955 -84.632133
-122.926375 -85.396122
-121.907795 -83.868143
-120.889215 -85.141459
-119.870635 -82.594828
-118.59741  -85.141459
-117.833475 -82.849491
-116.305605 -85.905448
-114.777735 -85.141459
-114.013799 -84.632133
-113.504509 -85.141459
-112.740574 -83.868143
-111.467349 -85.396122
-110.703414 -83.868143
-109.684834 -85.650785
-108.666254 -83.104154
-107.647674 -86.160112
-106.629094 -84.37747
-105.355869 -85.396122
-104.337289 -85.905448
-103.318709 -85.141459
-102.300128 -86.160112
-102.045483 -83.868143
-101.026903 -86.669438
-100.008323 -83.868143
-98.735098  -86.669438
-97.716518  -84.122807
-96.952583  -85.905448
-95.934003  -86.669438
-94.406133  -85.905448
-93.387553  -85.905448
-92.368973  -84.632133
-91.350392  -85.905448
-90.331812  -83.358817
-89.313232  -85.650785
-88.294652  -83.104154
-87.530717  -85.141459
-86.512137  -83.358817
-85.238912  -84.632133
-84.474977  -84.886796
-83.201752  -84.122807
-82.437817  -84.886796
-80.655301  -84.122807
-79.891366  -85.141459
-78.618141  -82.340165
-77.599561  -84.886796
-76.835626  -83.358817
-75.817046  -85.141459
-75.053111  -85.141459
-73.779886  -84.37747
-73.015951  -86.160112
-72.506661  -83.868143
-71.488081  -85.905448
-70.469501  -82.085502
-69.196275  -85.141459
-67.92305   -83.104154
-67.41376   -85.396122
-66.649825  -85.141459
-65.3766    -85.141459
-65.121955  -85.905448
-64.103375  -84.122807
-63.084795  -84.886796
-62.066215  -83.358817
-61.047635  -85.141459
-60.029055  -82.085502
-59.010475  -84.886796
-58.246539  -83.358817
-56.973314  -84.886796
-55.700089  -85.141459
-54.681509  -83.868143
-53.408284  -84.37747
-52.644349  -83.104154
-51.880414  -84.37747
-50.861834  -81.830838
-49.588609  -84.122807
-48.824674  -81.830838
-47.806094  -84.37747
-46.787513  -84.632133
-45.259643  -84.886796
-43.986418  -84.886796
-43.222483  -83.61348
-42.203903  -85.905448
-41.185323  -83.61348
-40.166743  -86.160112
-39.148163  -83.104154
-38.384228  -85.650785
-37.365648  -85.141459
-36.856358  -84.886796
-35.837777  -84.886796
-35.073842  -83.358817
-33.800617  -84.886796
-33.036682  -82.594828
-31.763457  -85.905448
-31.508812  -83.104154
-30.490232  -86.414775
-29.471652  -84.122807
-28.453072  -86.160112
-27.434492  -86.414775
-26.415912  -85.396122
-25.397332  -86.414775
-24.378751  -84.632133
-23.105526  -86.414775
-21.832301  -83.868143
-21.068366  -85.650785
-19.540496  -83.868143
-19.031206  -85.141459
-18.012626  -85.141459
-16.994046  -84.632133
-15.466176  -85.905448
-14.956886  -83.868143
-13.68366   -85.141459
-12.919725  -82.849491
-11.901145  -84.886796
-10.62792   -82.340165
-9.863985   -85.141459
-8.336115   -83.61348
-7.57218    -84.886796
-6.04431    -86.414775
-5.53502    -85.141459
-5.02573    -85.396122
-4.00715    -83.868143
-2.479279   -85.396122
-1.206054   -82.849491
-0.696764   -85.396122
-0.187474   -83.868143
1.085751    -86.160112
1.849686    -86.160112
3.122911    -85.905448
4.141491    -86.414775
4.905426    -84.632133
5.924006    -86.160112
6.178651    -83.358817
7.197231    -85.905448
8.215811    -82.594828
9.234392    -85.141459
10.252972   -84.632133
11.271552   -84.632133
13.054067   -85.396122
13.563357   -84.122807
14.836582   -85.141459
15.855162   -83.868143
```

I tried polyval, polyfit, Basic fitting (plot->tootls->basic fitting)

```
datasheet=xlsread('08_08_2019-11_08_58_.xlsx','Worksheet');
x=datasheet(:,1);
y=datasheet(:,2);
plot(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you understand under `trendline`? A linear line `p1*x+p2` can be achieved by the following code, which assumes that you have the **curve fitting toolbox** installed. The last part concerning `polyfit()` does not need this toolbox.
If you check [these (fit)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html) and [these (fitoptions)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fitoptions.html) docs, you'll find out that also other options, for quadratic polynomials, exponentials or fourier/sin-cos functions (and many more) are available when using the toolbox. The `x`and `y` of the data you posted looks like sinusoidal to me, so I'd go with the second option below.

#### Linear fit `p1*x+p2`

```
data = xlsread('08_08_2019-11_08_58_.xlsx');
x=data(:,1);
y=data(:,2);

[xData, yData] = prepareCurveData(x, y);

% Set up fittype and options.
ft = fittype('poly1')

% Fit model to data.
[fitresult, gof] = fit(xData, yData, ft);

% Plot fit with data.
figure
h = plot(fitresult, xData, yData);
legend(h, 'data', 'linear 1st order polynomial', 'Location', 'NorthEast');
xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); grid on

% Extract the equation(ft) and the coefficients
coeffnames(fitresult)
coeffvalues(fitresult)
```

[image: fitted linear line]

#### Using a Nonlinear Least Squares to fit a Fourier model `a0 + a1*cos(x*w) + b1*sin(x*w)`

```
data = xlsread('08_08_2019-11_08_58_.xlsx');
x=data(:,1);
y=data(:,2);

[xData, yData] = prepareCurveData(x, y);

% Set up fittype and options.
ft = fittype('fourier1')
opts = fitoptions('Method', 'NonlinearLeastSquares');

% Fit model to data.
[fitresult, gof] = fit(xData, yData, ft, opts);

% Plot fit with data.
figure
h = plot(fitresult, xData, yData);
legend(h, 'data', 'Fourier model fit', 'Location', 'NorthEast');
xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); grid on

% Extract the equation(ft) and the coefficients
coeffnames(fitresult)
coeffvalues(fitresult)
```

[image: fitted fourier model]

#### Using the `polyfit()` and `polyval()` functions for `p1*x+p2`:

```
% using polyfit and polyval (no toolbox needed)
data = xlsread('08_08_2019-11_08_58_.xlsx');
x=data(:,1);
y=data(:,2);

p = polyfit(x, y, 1)
pp = polyval(p, x);

h = plot(x, y, 'o', x, pp);
legend(h, 'data', 'linear 1st order polynomial', 'Location', 'NorthEast');
xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); grid on
```

[image: fitted line model]

#### Without Curve fitting toolbox, using your mentioned in-plot method

```
data = xlsread('08_08_2019-11_08_58_.xlsx');
x=data(:,1);
y=data(:,2);
plot(x, y)
```

In the figure window: **Tools -> Basic Fitting -> linear/polynomial**
also seems to work for your given case.
[image: fitted polynomials]

Comment: trend line means: a line indicating the general course or tendency of something, e.g. a geographical feature or a set of points on a graph. So I have to get it from the points I obtained.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had tried basic fitting... but it is showing that there are repeated x values and cannot be processed.

Comment: If I choose `linear` in basic fitting, I still get the same line plot as in the posted figures, which I generated by code. The message appears only in case you want to choose splines, but not in case of polynomials. Otherwise you can still use the `polyfit` variant I posted.

Comment: I added a plot derived by the basic-fitting method, showing all polynomials (linear to 10degree). The message appears due to your data. Does that answer your original question/solve your problem?